# Apply a function with if inside to a dataframe to take a value in a list in R

Tags: r, dataframe, function, apply

Hello everybody and thank you in advance for any help.

I inserted a txt file named "project" in R. This dataframe called "data" and consisted of 12 columns with some information of 999 households.

```
   head(data)

      im        iw        r am af a1c a2c a3c a4c a5c a6c a7c
1     0.00 20064.970 5984.282  0 38   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
2 15395.61  7397.191    0.000 42 30   1   0   0   0   0   0   0
3 16536.74 18380.770    0.000 33 28   1   0   0   0   0   0   0
4 20251.87 14042.250    0.000 38 38   1   1   0   0   0   0   0
5 17967.04 12693.240    0.000 24 39   1   0   0   0   0   0   0
6 12686.43 21170.450    0.000 62 42   0   0   0   0   0   0   0

im=male income
iw=female income
r=rent
am=male age
af=female age
a1c,a2c....a7c takes the value 1 when there is a child in age under 18
                 and the value 0 when there is not a child in the household.
```

Now i have to calculate the taxed income seperately for male and female for each houshold  based on some criteria, so i am trying to create 1 function which calculate 2 numbers and after that to apply this function on my data frame and return a list with these numbers.
Specificaly I want something like this:

```
fact<-function(im,iw,r,am,af,a1c,a2c,a3c,a4c,a5c,a6c,a7c){

 if ((am>0)&&(am<67)&&(af>0)) {mti<-im-(r)/2-(500*(a1c+a2c+a3c+a4c+a5c+a5c+a6c+a7c))}
 if ((am>0)&&(am<67)&&(af==0)) {mti<-im-r-(500*(a1c+a2c+a3c+a4c+a5c+a5c+a6c+a7c))}
 if ((am>=67)&&(af>0)) {mti<-im-1000-(r)/2-(500*(a1c+a2c+a3c+a4c+a5c+a5c+a6c+a7c))}
 if ((am<=67)&&(af==0)) {mti<-im-1000-r-(500*(a1c+a2c+a3c+a4c+a5c+a5c+a6c+a7c))}
 if ((af>0)&&(af<67)&&(am>0)) {fti<-iw-(r)/2-(500*(a1c+a2c+a3c+a4c+a5c+a5c+a6c+a7c))}
 if ((af>0)&&(af<67)&&(am==0)) {fti<-iw-r-(500*(a1c+a2c+a3c+a4c+a5c+a5c+a6c+a7c))}
 if ((af>=67)&&(am>0)) {fti<-iw-1000-(r)/2-(500*(a1c+a2c+a3c+a4c+a5c+a5c+a6c+a7c))}
 if ((af<=67)&&(am==0)) {fti<-iw-1000-r-(500*(a1c+a2c+a3c+a4c+a5c+a5c+a6c+a7c))}
 return(mti,fti)}
```

how can i fix this function in order to apply on my dataframe?
Can a function return 2 values?
how can i apply the function?

THEN I TRIED THIS:

```
fact<-function(im=data$im,iw=data$iw,r=data$r,am=data$am,af=data$af,a1c=data$a1c,a2c=data$a2c,a3c=data$a3c,a4c=data$a4c,a5c=data$a5c,a6c=data$a6c,a7c=data$a7c){


 if ((am>0)&&(am<67)&&(af>0)) {mti<-im-(r)/2-(500*(a1c+a2c+a3c+a4c+a5c+a5c+a6c+a7c))}
 if ((am>0)&&(am<67)&&(af==0)) {mti<-im-r-(500*(a1c+a2c+a3c+a4c+a5c+a5c+a6c+a7c))}
 if ((am>=67)&&(af>0)) {mti<-im-1000-(r)/2-(500*(a1c+a2c+a3c+a4c+a5c+a5c+a6c+a7c))}
 if ((am<=67)&&(af==0)) {mti<-im-1000-r-(500*(a1c+a2c+a3c+a4c+a5c+a5c+a6c+a7c))}
 if ((af>0)&&(af<67)&&(am>0)) {fti<-iw-(r)/2-(500*(a1c+a2c+a3c+a4c+a5c+a5c+a6c+a7c))}
 if ((af>0)&&(af<67)&&(am==0)) {fti<-iw-r-(500*(a1c+a2c+a3c+a4c+a5c+a5c+a6c+a7c))}
 if ((af>=67)&&(am>0)) {fti<-iw-1000-(r)/2-(500*(a1c+a2c+a3c+a4c+a5c+a5c+a6c+a7c))}
 if ((af<=67)&&(am==0)) {fti<-iw-1000-r-(500*(a1c+a2c+a3c+a4c+a5c+a5c+a6c+a7c))}
 return(mti,fti)}
 



fact(data[1,])
```

but i have tis error: Error in fact(data[1, ]) : object 'mti' not found

when i tried the function only for "fti" can run but wrongly.

Comment: to return multiple values, put the values in a list or vector - return ( c(mti, fti) )

Comment: I cannot do something because i have this error:

Comment: Error in fact(data[1, ]) : object 'mti' not found

Answer (score 0):

Besides the need to return multiple values using `c(mti, fti)`, your function doesn't have a default value if none of the conditions in the functions are TRUE. So, `mti` is never created.

Add `mti <- NA` at the start of your function, so NA is the default value.